# Error- Authorization header format is wrong, also not sure how to add signatureto the headers

Tags: python

I am having trouble running this code which calls an API to create certificate, every time it gives error that the format of header is wrong, if I add signature from postman et request then the error says signature mismatch, also I do not understand how to generate timestamp and nonce and assign it to the authorization header

```
import requests
import json

from ssss.hostgrid import ssssAuth
from urllib.parse import urljoin

url = 'https://hostname//cps/v2/enrollments?contractId=1-ABCDE'
s = requests.Session()
s.auth = hostnameAuth(
    client_token='ccccccccccccccccc',
    client_secret='ssssssssssssssssss',
    access_token='aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa'
)
payload = open('test.json',r)
data = json.load(payload)

# Add Authorization header to this snippet
headers = {
    "Accept": "application/vnd.aaaa.cps.enrollment-status.v1+json",
    "Content-Type": "application/vnd.aaaaa.cps.enrollment.v11+json"
}

response = requests.post(url, headers=headers)

print(response.text)
```